# Extract a specific word from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
#anotherdata=value#iamlookingforthis=226885#id=101&start=1
```

Given the string above how could I extract "iamlookingforthis=226885" in the string? value of it might change as this is dynamic. So, other instance might be "iamlookingforthis=1105". The location/sequence might also change, it could be in the middle or last part.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You told us what about the string might change, but in order to grab this specific part, we'll need to know what's *constant*. Is it always between `#`s? Is it always `iamlookingforthis`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Why `iamlookingforthis=226885` instead of e.g. `anotherdata=value` or `id=101&start=1`?

Comment: Why has this question got so many downvotes? I understood what OP was asking immediately. @OneNeptune the question clearly asks how to "extract". What has OP's question got to do with checking if a string contains a value?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to match a specific text.

Like this for example

```js
var str = '#anotherdata=value#iamlookingforthis=226885#id=101&start=1';
var value = str.match(/#iamlookingforthis=(\d+)/i)[1];

alert(value); // 226885
```

Explanation from Regex101:

`#iamlookingforthis=` matches the characters `#iamlookingforthis=` literally (case insensitive)

- 1st Capturing Group `(\d+)`

  - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Global pattern flags

  - `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of `[a-zA-Z]`)

See

- [RegExp on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) - try regex and see the explanation of it and results

---

Another alternative would be to split the string. You could split it by `#|?|&`.

```js
var str = '#anotherdata=value#iamlookingforthis=226885#id=101&start=1';
var parts = str.split(/[#\?&]/g); // split the string with these characters

// find the piece with the key `iamlookingforthis`
var filteredParts = parts.filter(function (part) {
  return part.split('=')[0] === 'iamlookingforthis';
});

// from the filtered array, get the first [0]
// split the value and key, and grab the value [1]
var iamlookingforthis = filteredParts[0].split('=')[1];

alert(iamlookingforthis); // 226885
```

Comment: var str = '#anotherdata=value#iamlookingforthis=226885#id=101&start=1';
var value = str.match(/#iamlookingforthis=(\d+)/i)[1];

alert(value); // 226885 

If I am not sure about what would be the value how will I modify the regex? It could be something like #iamlookingforthis=textvalue or #iamlookingforthis=alphanumeric or #iamlookingforthis=anything

Answer (score 3):

Here's a snippet:

```js
var str = '#anotherdata=value#iamlookingforthis=226885#id=101&start=1';

var extracted = str.split("#").find(function(v){ 
  return v.indexOf("iamlookingforthis") > -1;
});

alert(extracted); // iamlookingforthis=226885
```