# How can we extract specific part of the string from long string?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a HTML source code having mobile numbers in it. I want to extract just the phone numbers from that source code, each phone number has starting and ending flag. Lets say sample HTML code is, every mobile number starts from 'phone=' and ends with % as shown in below,

```
<code>
b2e1d163b0b<div class='container'></div>4dc6ebfa<h1>5&amp;t=s&amp;phone=95355036019918%40c.us&amp;i=1522996189s&amp;phone=95355025619123%40c.us&amp;i=1522996189""
</code>
```

How can I extract all phone numbers using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Please try substr() in Javascript or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515234/extract-a-specific-word-from-string-in-javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/exec):

```js
var str = "b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189s&phone=95355025619123%40c.us&i=1522996189";
var reg = /phone=(.*?)\%/g; // Anything between phone= and %
while ((matchArray = reg.exec(str)) !== null) { // Iterate over matchs
  console.log(`Found ${matchArray[1]}.`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using indexOf and substr functions

```
var test="b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189s&phone=95355025619123%40c.us&i=1522996189"
var start_point = test.indexOf("phone=)+6; 
//indexOf will return the location of "phone=", hence adding 6 to make start_point indicate the starting location of phone number
var phone_number = test.substr(start_location,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom logic that make use of `split()` on `&phone=` and then get the `substr()` for each item of the splitted array by checking if `%` exist or not.

```js
var str = "b2e1d163b0b4dc6ebfa5&t=s&phone=95355036019918%40c.us&i=1522996189s&phone=95355025619123%40c.us&i=1522996189";
var strArray = str.split('&phone=');
var phoneNumber = [];
strArray.forEach((item)=>{
  var indexOfPercent = item.indexOf('%');
  if(indexOfPercent !== -1){
    phoneNumber.push(item.substr(0, indexOfPercent));
  }
});
console.log(phoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the items using:

```
var rawPhoneNumbers = myText.split("phone=");
var phoneNumbers = [];
if (rawPhoneNumbers.length > 1) {
    for (var index = 0; index < rawPhoneNumbers.length; index++) {
        if (rawPhoneNumbers[index].indexOf("%") > -1) {
            phoneNumbers.push(rawPhoneNumbers[index].substring(0, rawPhoneNumbers[index].indexOf("%")));
        }
    }
}
console.log(rawPhoneNumbers);
```