# How to pull out a portion from long string of metadata

Tags: javascript, json, string, substring

This is my first time working with very long metadata in an api response.  I would like to dig into the metadata and only pull out the image_url. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do so than splicing this extremely long string a bunch of times.  In this example here is the metadata:

```
"metadata": "{\"id\":4647,\"name\":\"Pancake\",\"generation\":10,\"created_at\":\"2017-11-24T09:35:05.000Z\",\"birthday\":\"2017-11-24T00:00:00.000Z\",\"image_url\":\"https://img.cryptokitties.co/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/4647.svg\",\"image_url_cdn\":\"https://img.cn.cryptokitties.co/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/4647.svg\",\"color\":\"mintgreen\",\"kitty_type\":null,\"is_fancy\": .... etc
```

I only want the portion of the very long metadata string for image_url that is "https://img.cryptokitties.co/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/4647.svg"

Any suggestions on what is the most efficient way to achieve this?

I tried [How can we extract specific part of the string from long string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464570/how-can-we-extract-specific-part-of-the-string-from-long-string) solution but I have lots of objects in my json response so I would need to iterate over everything and use a while loop.  It seemed overly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse()` on the metadata string to get a JavaScript object. From that you can just index the object with the `image_url` key.

Example:

```
const metadata = JSON.parse(response['metadata'])
const imageUrl = metadata['image_url'];
```

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it solves your problem, thank you!